# Pointer in c++ struct name

Tags: c++

I ran into this bit of code for a c++ linked list implementation.

```
struct node
{
    int info;
    struct node *next;
}*start;
```

What does this mean to have `*start` rather than just `start`??

What happens when it is later used like this? What does `s` mean it is not referenced anywhere else in the function?

```
struct node *temp, *s;
temp = new(struct node);
```

Comment: Hint: It's the same as if you had written: `node *start`; afterwards.

Comment: So if that declaration is outside of a class definition then start is just an unowned pointer to a node?

Comment: I wouldn't say unowned, but yes, uninitialized.

Comment: I would suggest to ignore this example. `struct node { }` creates a type called `node` (unlike C) and `node` can be used without repeating `struct` or using a `typedef`. Also, `} *start;` declares a global variable `start` that is a pointer to `node` (another reason to ignore this example).

Comment: That's why semicolon required after `struct/class/union` declaration - there could be variable list. Though it is rarely used in C++ novadays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fragment

```
struct node
{
    int info;
    struct node *next;
}*start;
```

is equivalent to

```
struct node
{
    int info;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *start;
```

So in your first fragment, you define a structure named `node` and a variable named `start` of type `struct node *` within one statement. That's all.

Note that in C++ (unlike in C), you could also write

```
struct node
{
    int info;
    node *next;
};
node *start;
```

i.e. you can omit the `struct`-keyword when defining variables of type `struct node`.